# Problems self hosting WCF service under Windows 7 Home Premium

Tags: wcf

I am self hosting a WCF service in a windows forms tooltray app.

Under Windows 7 Professional I can communicate successfully with the service but under Windows Home Premium I have to run the app as an administrator.

Any ideas why this happens and what I can do under Home Premium so I don't have to run as an admin?

More Info

I don't believe that UAC has been turned off on Win 7 Pro. I tried it on 2 Win 7 Pro boxes and both worked.

I'm using basicHttpBinding

Comment: Can you provide more information: Is UAC disabled for your Win 7 Pro box? What binding are you using? basicHTTPBinding?

Comment: Try reading this thread: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wcf/thread/b9cdcef2-b39c-498f-b7a9-dbedf3f84163/

Comment: Thanks Morten. If you write this as a question I'll mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More information about user rights on a WCF service using basicHTTPBinding: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wcf/thread/b9cdcef2-b39c-498f-b7a9-dbedf3f84163/

Comment: Thanks Morten. Registering the url using httpcfg as listed in the link worked well.